# Queue does not take parameters in java

Tags: java

I have a problem in my code
I'm not being able to add Queue

When I tried to add this code

```
Queue<Integer> myqu = new LinkedList<>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i <= mySecondArray.length + 1; i++){
    myqu.add(mySecondArray[i]);
}
```

To this code

```
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Queue; 
import java.util.*; 

class test{

static class Queue{  

    static Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<Integer>();  
Queue<Integer> myqu = new LinkedList<>(); 


    static int[] intArray = new int[]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; 
    static int[] mySecondArray = new int[10];               

    static void enQueue(){

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++){
             s1.push(intArray[i]);  
        }
        System.out.printf("\nBefore multiply operation\n");
        System.out.printf("%s \n",s1);

        System.out.printf("\nAfter multiply operation\n");
        Integer edit = s1.pop();
        System.out.printf("[");
        for (int i = 1; i <= s1.size() + 1; i++){
            mySecondArray[i] = i * 2;
            edit = Integer.valueOf(i) * 2;  
            System.out.printf("%s",edit);   
            System.out.printf(", ");            
        }
        System.out.printf("]");     

    for (int i = 0; i <= mySecondArray.length + 1; i++){
    myqu.add(mySecondArray[i]);
}
    }  

};  

public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    Queue q = new Queue();  
    q.enQueue();  
}  
}
```

It says " error: type Queue does not take parameters
        Queue myqu = new LinkedList();"

Could you correct the code, Please

Comment: your `static class Queue` is not a generic class (it has no type parameter `<T>`), therefore you are not allowed to write `Queue<Integer>`. Instead you have to write `Queue myqu = new Queue();`

Answer (score 0):

You are geeting this issue because your class name and interface `Queue` name is same.

Change you class  name and this issue will resolve like:

```
static class SampleQueue{
  ..your code

}
```

And change your main method for new name:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    SampleQueue q = new SampleQueue();  
    q.enQueue();  
}
```

Comment: This still won't work because SampleQueue is static, so you can't use `new`, it would have to be `SampleQueue.enQueue();`

Comment: This will work fine, you can try.  See static classes in java doc for more details.

Comment: Sumit, typo on my part, I meant OP's `myqu` was static so .add() will not work.  While you CAN create an instance and access members, it is not the correct way to do so. Why pass bad habits on to somebody who is learning.  You can compile code with infinite loops and memory leaks too

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use java.util.Queue, why are you creating your own inner static class called Queue?  Rename your Queue class, and it's also declared static, so you can't instantiate it with `new`
Also you `myqu` is not declared static, so you need to fix that as well, I renamed it myQueue in the code below as per naming conventions

```
public class test {

    static class QueueUtil {

        static Stack<Integer> s1   = new Stack<Integer>();
        static Queue<Integer> myQueue = new LinkedList<>();


        static int[] intArray      = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        static int[] mySecondArray = new int[10];

        static void enQueue() {

            for (int value : intArray) {
                s1.push(value);
            }
            System.out.print("\nBefore multiply operation\n");
            System.out.printf("%s \n", s1);

            System.out.print("\nAfter multiply operation\n");
            Integer edit = s1.pop();
            System.out.print("[");
            for (int i = 1; i <= s1.size() + 1; i++) {
                mySecondArray[i] = i * 2;
                edit             = i * 2;
                System.out.printf("%s", edit);
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print("]");

            for (int i = 0; i <= mySecondArray.length + 1; i++) {
                myQueue.add(mySecondArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueUtil.enQueue();
    }
}
```

This code should fix your issue that you asked about, but I think you're not going to get the results you're expecting... 
I recommend reading up on how, when and why to use static, there are a lot of great posts on here.